# JSON editor/formatter?

Tags: json, serialization

I've got some JSON data, but it's all on one line. Does anyone know of a web or Windows editor that will format (e.g. indent and insert new lines) this data for me, so I can read it better? Preferably one that uses a GUI to display the JSON—instead of a command-line tool that outputs a reformatted document, for example.

Comment: **See Also:** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/998832

Comment: http://jsonlint.com/ can be used.

Comment: https://www.w3dnetwork.com/json-formatter.html -- is simple, and with multiple views, also as they claim they do not store any data , so you can use it to format sensitive data also.

Comment: Have you tried this? https://devtoolsonline20190908040816.azurewebsites.net/DevTools/Prettify_JSON

Comment: you can download this extention for google chrome and it fill format your json:https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/json-formatter/bcjindcccaagfpapjjmafapmmgkkhgoa/related?hl=en

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried this?

http://jsonformat.com/

Comment: formatter only -- it doesn't help you edit ( no syntax highlight or anything )

Comment: (and if you have a syntax error, it does not show you where)

Comment: i think that this is better https://devtoolsonline20190908040816.azurewebsites.net/DevTools/Prettify_JSON

Comment: https://www.devprimetools.com/json-viewer - It supports search/filter in JSON. You can also view your JSON in a tabular/diagrammatic format. It has features like fetch data from REST API and saving JSON for future use.

Comment: I use https://www.atrowel.com/tool/json-tool.html

Answer (score 8):

I have recently created JSON Editor Online, a tool to easily edit and format JSON online. JSON is displayed in a clear, editable treeview and in formatted plain text.

http://jsoneditoronline.org/

Comment: Haha.
It's great.
Before I found yours, my attempt was chrome dev tools > js console > write var x = *my_json*. Then I explore it the geeks way :P

Comment: Well designed and easy to use. Great work!

Comment: well done. Very quick and smooth.

Comment: I tried your tool an it's very nice. But, it will not validate valid JSON where there is a mutilined string assignment. The string has to be continuous without line breaks.

Answer (score 5):

You can download http://www.thomasfrank.se/json_editor.html and run it locally on your own data, although it is an editor rather than a formatter.

http://www.jsonlint.com/ is also a useful validation and reformatting tool.

Answer (score 5):

On windows I go for: http://jsonviewer.codeplex.com/

Handy for pulling raw JSON responses from Firebug and parsing it for me.

Comment: Great! Works on Linux too (using Mono).

Answer (score 2):

I use http://curiousconcept.com/jsonformatter to format computer generated jsons. It makes it much readable.

Comment: pretty good -- shows you exactly where your syntax is wrong ( but not as-you-type, only when you click to "process" button )

Answer (score 2):

Remember that JSON is just a Javascript Object Literal with fancy clothes.  You should be able to use any [Javascript Beautifier](http://elfz.laacz.lv/beautify/) to clean it up.

Answer (score 0):

I like this one here:
http://freeformatter.com/json-formatter.html

The validation process is flexible if your doc does not adhere to the RFC standards.  It also creates a tree with collapsible nodes which is cool when you want to work in a small area of the json tree

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I do: use the Aptana Eclipse Javascript Editor, which will check your syntax as you type.  There's only one trick:  you have to wrap your json in a tiny bit of javascript to make the whole thing a valid javascript file, and eliminate those red and yellow syntax errors.

So, the outer-most `{}`  becomes:  `x={};` ( with all your json stuff in the middle ).

Now you just have to strip-off the `x=` and the `;` before parsing as JSON.
I do this in a function that wraps the jQuery ajax function:

```
function get_json_file(url,options,callback){
    var opts = {dataType:"text"};
    opts.url = url;
    $.extend(opts,options);
    opts.success=function(data){
        var json = data.substring(data.indexOf('{'),data.lastIndexOf('}')+1);
        var obj = JSON.parse(json);
        callback(obj);
    };
    $.ajax(opts);
}
```

It's a bit crazy, but it's worth it to effectively have a really good syntax-checking JSON editor in eclipse.