# GUI-based or Web-based JSON editor that works like property explorer

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, editor, wysiwyg

**Background:** This is a request for something that may not exist yet, but I've been meaning to build one for a long time. First I will ask if anyone has seen anything like it yet.

Suppose you have an arbitrary JSON structure like the following:

```
{
    'title_str':'My Employee List'
    ,'lastmod_str': '2009-June-15'
    ,'employee_table':[
        {'firstname':'john','lastname':'doe','age':'33',}
        ,{'firstname':'jane','lastname':'doe','age':'34',}
        ,{'firstname':'samuel','lastname':'doe','age':'35',}
    ]
}
```

**Question:** Is there a web-based JSON editor that could take a structure like this, and automatically allow the user to modify this in a user-friendly GUI?

**Example:** Imagine an auto-generated HTML form that displays 2 input-type-text controls for both title and lastmod, and a table of input-type-text controls with three columns and three rows for arr_list ... with the ability to delete or add additional rows by clicking on a [+][X] next to each row in the table.

**Big Idea:** The "big idea" behind this is that the user would be able to specify any arbitrary (non-recursive) JSON structure and then also be able to edit the structure with a GUI-based interaction (this would be similar to the "XML Editor Grid View" in XML Spy).

**See also:**

- [Is there a JSON api based CMS that is hosted locally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22582471/is-there-a-json-api-based-cms-that-is-hosted-locally)
- https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/37237/treetable-as-a-flexible-condition-filter-editor
- [JSON-editor](https://json-editor.github.io/json-editor/)
- [YAML GUI](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=yaml+gui)

**Update: (Thu 2014-07-31 18:31:11)**

A github repository has been created to further track this closed SO post.

- https://github.com/dreftymac/stackoverflow.questions.998832

Comment: Do you have any progress on building own editor? i was looking for the same thing. What i have found on the net are almost same ones as you listed on your answer.

Comment: No. It seems like a good enough idea with not enough momentum behind it.

Comment: if i get enough momentum for it i'd love to write my first cocoa app for that, if you won't ask for copyrights;)

Comment: I'm too small to put a wall around any of my ideas, and this has been done before anyway :) ... take a look at the XMLSPY grid-view editor if you decide to tackle this and you need additional inspiration: http://www.altova.com/xmlspy/xml-grid-view.html

Comment: I've been thinking of this, and found your question when checking if there was demand for it. when checking to see if there waas demand putting a prototype together

Comment: @dreftymac I've been thinking of this for a product, and found your question when checking for interest. I've put a 0.1 prototype together, with your question in mind (and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3369735/json-gui-creator-editor) . It creates the form based on a template JSON: the user can enter text; and add/delete from list items. But: it doesn't yet use a table for lists (instead, nested panes); doesn't allow fieldnames to be edited (a safety feature); and it's in Java not Javascript (but could be an applet) - are you interested in having a look?

Comment: Have a look at http://visualjsoneditor.codeplex.com its an app which creates an editor gui based on a json schema

Comment: **See also:** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22582471/is-there-a-json-api-based-cms-that-is-hosted-locally

Comment: 'employee_table' element MUST be replaces with strings array. Also you normally provide separate schema with human-readible column headers.. As a json fan I must state You have selected bad solution for this particular use case. its task for sql with one to many relations

Comment: If I would face that kind of artificial strange problem, the easiest way to get that rendered (convert json to html) can be done with react.js Json is very native to js, and rendering html is very native to jsx. So, Just one js source + even no need for a line in backend. Renderer Tool could easily be written under an hour..

Comment: **//'employee_table' element MUST be replaces with strings array//** Do you have a citation or reference for this statement? It sounds like a personal preference being promoted as a requirement with no context or explanation.

Comment: I have found this one pretty helpful as it parses the json, shows the error line number if json is not correct, beautifies the json and remove the whitespaces it need be:    https://devtechfactory.com/json

Answer (score 395, accepted):

**Update:** In an effort to answer my own question, here is what I've been able to uncover so far. If anyone else out there has something, I'd still be interested to find out more.

- http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html ;; knockoutjs.com nice
- http://jsonviewer.arianv.com/ ;; Cute minimal one that works offline
- http://www.alkemis.com/jsonEditor.htm ; this one looks pretty nice
- http://json.bubblemix.net/ Visualise JSON structute, edit inline and export back to prettified JSON.
- http://jsoneditoronline.org/ Example added by StackOverflow thread participant. Source: https://github.com/josdejong/jsoneditor
- http://jsonmate.com/
- http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/
- [mb21.github.io/JSONedit](http://mb21.github.io/JSONedit/), built as an Angular directive

**Based on JSON Schema**

- https://github.com/json-editor/json-editor
- https://github.com/mozilla-services/react-jsonschema-form
- https://github.com/json-schema-form/angular-schema-form
- https://github.com/joshfire/jsonform
- https://github.com/gitana/alpaca
- https://github.com/marianoguerra/json-edit
- https://github.com/exavolt/onde
- Tool for generating JSON Schemas: http://www.jsonschema.net
- http://metawidget.org
- Visual JSON Editor, Windows Desktop Application (free, open source), http://visualjsoneditor.org/

**Commercial (No endorsement intended or implied, may or may not meet requirement)**

- [Liquid XML - JSON Schema Editor](https://www.liquid-technologies.com/json-schema-editor) Graphical JSON Schema editor and validator.
- http://www.altova.com/download-json-editor.html
- [XML ValidatorBuddy](http://www.xml-buddy.com/ValidatorBuddy.htm) - JSON and XML editor supports JSON syntax-checking, syntax-coloring, auto-completion, JSON Pointer evaluation and JSON Schema validation.

**jQuery**

- [formbuilder jQuery drag and drop](https://formbuilder.online/)
- [formeo](http://draggable.github.io/formeo/)
- [shalotelli form_builder](http://shalotelli.github.com/form_builder/)

**YAML**

- [Konstellate Reddit Post](https://www.reddit.com/r/kubernetes/comments/ao6ggd/konstellate_editor_a_gui_to_build_yaml_files)

**See Also**

- [Google blockly](https://developers.google.com/blockly/guides/overview)
- [Is there a JSON api based CMS that is hosted locally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22582471/is-there-a-json-api-based-cms-that-is-hosted-locally#22607952)
- cms-based concept ;; http://www.webhook.com/
- tree-based widget ;; http://mbraak.github.io/jqTree/
- http://mjsarfatti.com/sandbox/nestedSortable/
- http://jsonviewer.codeplex.com/
- http://xmlwebpad.codeplex.com/
- http://tadviewer.com/
- https://studio3t.com/knowledge-base/articles/visual-query-builder/

Comment: [Form Builder](http://app.formassembly.com/form-builder3.4.2/?) made with Freja looks amazing! Though this is (almost) completely unrelated to the question... :P

Comment: @Cawas It does look amazing. It's surprising, but there are several excellent form-builders out there - one (wufoo) was recently acquired for... $35 million http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2481576

Comment: @13ren damn, I've never realized there was such a market behind all this!

Comment: +1 for http://jsoneditoronline.org
Here is GIT of this project - https://github.com/wjosdejong/jsoneditoronline

Comment: another simple implementation of json form composer:
https://bitbucket.org/zakis_/jquery-jsonbuilder

Comment: Just skimmed through the JSON schema projects. Alpaca seems to be the most active and complete, and is also working on a drag and drop designer to complement it. Definitely my pick.

Comment: jsoneditoronline git link no longer works.

Comment: @jeromeyers: You're right.so I have found working project link here : [https://github.com/josdejong/jsoneditor](https://github.com/josdejong/jsoneditor)

Comment: One of the editors above was integrated into an Atom package: https://github.com/LukasHechenberger/atom-json-editor

Comment: New project of Web page database with DOM rendering and JSON editor http://js2dx.com

Comment: Is there anything that can give me the JSON path of the key I select? The chrome devtools window seems to do it, and it's really handy.

(See - "4. Copy property path"  ) https://techbrij.com/chrome-developer-tools-inspect-json-path-query

Comment: One more I am using recently is https://www.devprimetools.com/json-viewer . It supports search/filter in JSON. You can also view your JSON in a tabular/diagrammatic format. It has features like fetch data from REST API and saving JSON for future use.

Comment: @KanchanKumar it looks like that link is broken?

Answer (score 4):

Generally when I want to create a JSON or YAML string, I start out by building the Perl data structure, and then running a simple conversion on it.  You could put a UI in front of the Perl data structure generation, e.g. a web form.

Converting a structure to JSON is very straightforward:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use JSON::Any;

my $data = { arbitrary structure in here };
my $json_handler = JSON::Any->new(utf8=>1);
my $json_string = $json_handler->objToJson($data);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm also unfamiliar with perl forms. Any recommendations for a simple form maker? It's really just a very small part of a project I'm working on so I don't like to spend too much time on building the form/UI instead of the real logic and algorithm I'm writing :)