# JSON editor, preferably for Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2008, json

I was wondering if anyone knows of any good JSON editors, preferably one that is a plugin for Visual Studio 2008?

Comment: Isnt JOSN just javascript? Why does VS have a problem with that?

Comment: Just create a new js file and write there all you want.

Comment: I was wondering if there was something like http://www.jsonpro.com that was a plugin.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/998832 (similar question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Online JSON-editor](http://braincast.nl/samples/jsoneditor/)

Comment: There are a lot of high quality, web based, JSON editors, but I'm not comfortable using a web solution when I'm working with sensitive data.

Answer (score 0):

[This one is nice](http://www.thomasfrank.se/json_editor.html); it also features adding elements and clipboard functionality (visually on the tree, without messing with code).

It is a static web page, so it can be easily downloaded and used locally.

Answer (score 0):

XmlGrid.net has a good online JSON editor. One nice feature is that you can toggle XmlView and JsonView so that you can easily convert Json to XML. Here is the URL:
http://xmlgrid.net/jsonEditor.html