# Simple structured data (INI, YAML, JSON, etc) editor application

Tags: json, editor, yaml

I am looking for a standalone application that will allow administrators to easily edit data in a structured format that is easy to parse (INI, YAML, JSON, etc). Although I can find very complex and sophisticated XML editors, I can't find anything simple - all I want is an application that will read a simple file and allow admins to edit them in a structured way - they click on the file, the app opens it as a form, they fill in or edit the blanks, and the app saves the data in one of the simple formats listed above. I don't want them to use a text editor because I want it to be as simple as possible and I don't want there to be any possibility that the admins will make any formatting errors.

There have been several times in my career when such a tool would have been useful, but I've never been able to find one. Preferably it would be Open Source and run on both OSX and Windows.

Comment: **See Also:** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/998832

Answer (score 0):

If you choose YAML you do not a special tool. Any text editor would be enough. Make your YAML document look like a form.
INI file is too simple and JSON may be not very readable.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the links available here:

[GUI-based or Web-based JSON editor that works like property explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998832/web-based-json-editor-that-works-like-property-explorer-with-ajaxy-input-form/999124#999124)