# Web based XML Editor

Tags: xml

can anyone suggest an "web based" xml editor? (preferably open source)

Ideally, I would like a "grid" view that mimics:

http://www.oxygenxml.com/xml_grid_editor.html

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/998832/web-based-json-editor-that-works-like-property-explorer-with-ajaxy-input-form/999124#999124

Comment: @Cawas, how is that related? It is mainly about JSON Editors.

Comment: @bottleboot because it does give *web based grid editors*, even if most of them are JSON (there are a few links to XML ones as well) which could be used for XML if tweaked a little bit.

Comment: I see. I didn't find any of those useful for XML editing though.

Comment: I would like to protest against the policy of closing a perfectly normal question as "non-constructive". 

I, for one, sorely need an input on this one, and I opened a similar question, just to be rubberstamped with all kinds of names. In a sister website of StackOverflow, I was told that StackOverflow is the best place to look for an answer. 

This kind of purism is, borrowing your own terminology, not constructive.

Comment: @VadimBerman welcome to SO, where many constructive things are put off in name of the efforts of keeping it clean. Something must be working here, but I still share the frustration with you.

Comment: There's an answer to this question on [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange here.](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/56635/36725).

Answer (score 4):

Thought a bit late, here's an open source suggestion: http://xmlwebpad.codeplex.com/

Here's another paid version also very alike: http://www.altova.com/xmlspy/xml-grid-view.html

And here's a free online only (I believe): http://www.online-xml-editor.com/

Comment: try https://xmleditoronline.org/