# JSON GUI creator/editor

Tags: java, perl, json, user-interface, forms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [GUI-based or Web-based JSON editor that works like property explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998832/gui-based-or-web-based-json-editor-that-works-like-property-explorer)

I'm using text files in JSON format as input to my java/perl programs.

I would like to allow novice users to generate such JSON files themselves, following some template. Is there some GUI that allows easy, step-by-step creation of a JSON file?

It should allow filling in fields with text, choosing file locations etc. Also note the input format is not totally fixed - for example there are a couple of arrays where the number of elements can be chosen by the user, so the GUI should account for this flexibility too.

Thanks!

Comment: I've been thinking of this for a product, and found your question when checking for interest. I've put a 0.1 prototype together, with your question in mind (and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/998832/web-based-json-editor-that-works-like-property-explorer-with-ajaxy-input-form) . It creates the form based on a template JSON: the user can enter text; and add/delete from list items. But: file locations are not specially handled yet (JSON has no type for file). It's in Java - are you interested in having a look?