# Does anyone know of a UI grid control that can display nested JSON or XML?

Tags: xml, json, gridview, grid, nested

Ideally it would display like Altova XMLSpy "enhanced grid" view:

for an example:

[image: http://s16.a-img.com/images/shots/json-outline.gif]

I'm looking for something for Windows platform, or Java platform.

Thanks!

Comment: By "Windows" do you mean .Net? Also have you considered using a treeview instead? - Depending on the data it might be more user friendly.

Comment: Yes - .Net is fine, or native Windows. Or java on any platform.

Comment: Treeview could work maybe - I haven't looked for any nice Treeview controls that can take JSON data; I've been so obsessed looking for a grid like XMLSpy's ... Are they any you can recommend?

Comment: Treeview is almost as bad as looking at formatted JSON text. I'm open to commercial products as well. I could've sworn there were some very advanced grid controls out there that nest cells within cells, etc..

Comment: I mainly code for Silverlight, where I think it should be pretty easy to code. Though you might want to use WPF, if there's no need for making it webbased. There're many grid controls for WPF (including at least one build in), and you could simply nest the controls.

Comment: This is a duplicate question. Please see:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/998832/web-based-json-editor-that-works-like-property-explorer-with-ajaxy-input-form

Answer (score 1):

This has been asked elsewhere, you were looking for the same thing I was looking for. Apparently you want something that runs on the desktop, I wanted something that runs in the browser:

Search the web for:
"Web-based JSON editor that works like property explorer with AJAXy input form"

See also:

[GUI-based or Web-based JSON editor that works like property explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998832)
http://s16.a-img.com/images/shots/json-outline.gif (I wanted the same thing, but in the browser)

Answer (score 0):

http://xmlgrid.codeplex.com/

**Project Description**

XmlGridControl is .NET Windows Forms grid control for XML data in table format viewing. 
Adding this controls gives your application an opportunity to have a professional XML-editor appearance.

Answer (score 0):

I think that editor [XiMpLe](http://www.ximple.cz) is exactly what you were looking for. It can edit XML and JSON files and the grid view is similar to XMLSpy.

[Your example in XiMpLe grid view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpPEV.png)