# JSON object GUI

Tags: javascript, json, user-interface

I'd like to offer my users an interface to edit JSON objects.

For example I have a JavaScript that calls Google charts with the following options:

```
var options={
    chartType: "Pie",
    title:"Chart title",
    is3D:false,
    width:500,
    height:300,
};
```

Ideally my users should be able to modify the options themselves without having to look into the code. They would be presented with a UI automatically built from the object, where:

- chartType is a select (Pie, Line, Bar)
- title is a text input
- is3D is a checkbox
- etc.

Are there libraries for this? If not, any suggestion to get started?

I could of course build the form manually, but the idea is to have a generic solution that works for any object.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/998832/gui-based-or-web-based-json-editor-that-works-like-property-explorer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found this link with conventions for describing JSON: http://www.json-schema.org/

Searching for "JSON schema" led me to a number of solutions, and in particular this post:

[GUI-based or Web-based JSON editor that works like property explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998832/web-based-json-editor-that-works-like-property-explorer-with-ajaxy-input-form)

It was started two years ago, but is apparently well documented and kept up to date.

Also, a post from April 2012 on the ibm website:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-jsonschema/index.html?cmp=dw&cpb=dwwdv&ct=dwnew&cr=dwnen&ccy=zz&csr=040512

Answer (score 1):

**Problem**

How to provide a user-friendly means of constructing arbitrary JSON structures where:

- the user interface is intuitive, flexible and capable of use without developer-level technical proficiency
- the user interface can be inferred from the structure of the JSON
- modifications to the user interface require little or no developer intervention
- modifications to the underlying JSON structure can automatically trigger modifications to the corresponding user interface

**Solution**

If this is the basic premise of the question, this approach does appear to be possible using any of various approaches under the "MVVM" nomenclature (which is apparently a variant of the "MVC" meme).

**Examples**

http://knockoutjs.com/examples/cartEditor.html
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel#Open_source_MVVM_frameworks

**See Also**

[GUI-based or Web-based JSON editor that works like property explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998832/gui-based-or-web-based-json-editor-that-works-like-property-explorer)

Answer (score 0):

Write a webform to detect the parameters of the a service.
Once you have the parameters, generate your form based on parameters available.
Submit your form and grab the JSON Result.

Comment: It makes sense, but I am looking for a more generic solution. Some of my objects are not even linked to a service, they are just consumed directly by my script.

Comment: check out how Fiddler intercepts JSON

Answer (score 0):

Na, you will need to build the form yourself. HTML forms are just a way to describe requirements for properties (of a request), and their serialisation will just return the desired object. In your example it would be

```
<select name="chartType"><option value="Pie"/><option value="Line" />...</select>
<input type="text" name="title" />
<input type="checkbox" name="is3D" />
<input type="number" name="width" />
```

etc. Forms also allow you to describe patterns, min/max-values, default values and everything such a library would handle. You might find a library that turns a simple

```
{
    chartType: ["Pie", "Line", "Bar"],
    title:"string",
    is3D:"boolean",
    width:"number"
}
```

into the above html and provides a crossbrowser serialisation function, but when it gets more complicated (e.g. preselect "Line", have a default title etc) you will be back to the html (or a js representation of it).

Comment: thx, your object description is kind of what I was looking for. I was hoping to find a library for this, or at least learn about usual conventions (e.g. how to describe a drop-down vs. radio buttons).

Comment: No, thats html. select list, drop-down select list, radio buttons? You only said you'd like to have a choice between options.