# Is there a JSON api based CMS that is hosted locally?

Tags: json, content-management-system

I'm looking for a CMS that just outputs JSON data.

I've done some research and found a few possibilities.
But all the 'API based' CMS I found were hosted in the cloud.

A few examples that are exactly what I want.. but in the cloud:

- https://www.contentful.com
- https://prismic.io
- https://buttercms.com
- https://www.cloudcms.com

I'm looking for a CMS with functionality like this but hosted myself.

**Requirements for the CMS I'm looking for:**

- A user can add/update data in the CMS
- Can create a custom object template in the CMS. For example: an object with a title, rating, image, short intro and a full text
- I can request a URL and I get a JSON output with the data

*I only need to GET content no to add new data. (not a problem if this is also possible to :)*

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Try [goms](https://github.com/artpar/goms), its a self-hosted baas.

Comment: https://github.com/directus/directus

Comment: It sounds like [FrontAid CMS](https://frontaid.io/) could be interesting for you. While it also runs in the cloud, it connects to your own (local) Git repository and commits the JSON content directly into that. So you don't even need an API. Disclaimer: I work at FrontAid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try my framework,

admin: http://123.bl.ee/cms/objengine/admin.php?userid=cms.sa
pass: tim

Admin user can define custom object, regular user can add/update/delete data.

JSON output:
http://123.bl.ee/cms/objengine/ajax.php?objectname=ExampleObject

Comment: This is looks good! Only thing I'm missing is a WYSIWYG editor and a way to upload/link videos. But I can probably find a workaround for that.

Is it possible to host this on my own server?

Comment: Yes, I can send you php source, here is github link https://github.com/vujovicigor/objEngine
but it is old version on github, I will make commit in few days.

Comment: Okay thanks! I'll keep an eye on it.

Comment: Send me an email, my address is on admin login page