# Generate forms on-the-fly using EmberJS and JSON schema?

Tags: json, ember.js, schema

I searched and found this question ([GUI-based or Web-based JSON editor that works like property explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998832/gui-based-or-web-based-json-editor-that-works-like-property-explorer)) that has several links to resources that generate UI from JSON.

I am interested in any examples or known projects that show emberjs working with JSON Schema (http://json-schema.org/) to generate on-the-fly Forms.  Projects such as:

- Alpacajs(http://www.alpacajs.org)
- json-editor(https://github.com/jdorn/json-editor)

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can trivially generate forms dynamically based on some JSON.

You will need to map your JSON object into an array of keys in your router (or controller):

```
model: function() {
  var json = {a: 'red', b: 'yellow', c: 'blue'};
  var items = [], key;
  for (key in json) {
    if (json.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      items.push({name: key, value: json[key]});
    }
  }
  return items;
}
```

And just use the `each` helper in your view:

```
{{#each field in content}}
  {{field.name}}: {{input type="text" value=field.value}}<br>
{{/each}}
```

I made a working [JSBin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/pojamosuco/1/edit?html,js,output) with the above code.

Answer (score 1):

There is Ember addon - [ember-cli-dynamic-forms](https://toddjordan.github.io/ember-cli-dynamic-forms/#/demos/basic-usage).

This addon is powered by alpacajs.