# Is there any embedable web text/json editor providing auto-completion based on json-schemas?

Tags: autocomplete, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I know there is a short list of editors that *may* support auto-completion based on json-schemas: VSCode, Atom (with plugin), but configuration and embedding these editors inside a web page with the plugins is not as easy (or possible). On the other side, there is a multitude of web based editors. Yet, could not find one that actually provides auto completion based on a (custom) JSON schema.

Any idea?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there aren't any today. It's something I'd like to add to jsonschema.dev - Please feel free to file an issue, but I likely won't be able to get to it any time soon.

Comment: That might come in handy for many uses..

Comment: I've made a note. I DO love the editing in VSCode. I don't know how much effort it would be to include something like that.

Comment: There's https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/ - Yet I dont thik it can do everything that VSCode can...

Comment: Indeed. Bookmarked. I currently use codemirror, but may move. Also just found this: https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html#extending-language-services-configure-json-defaults

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998832/gui-based-or-web-based-json-editor-that-works-like-property-explorer