# Customisable GUI for generating JSON

Tags: json, user-interface

I'm wondering if there's an application out there that can help me with this. Assuming I've defined a JSON schema, I want to generate a GUI that lets me build objects that conform to this schema without hard-writing the JSON myself. Each field would provide a simple GUI element labelled with that field's key.

For example:

- A string field in the schema would provide a text field.
- A string field which can only take specific strings would ideally be a drop-down list containing those strings.
- A number field would either be a spinner or a text field that only accepts numbers.
- A boolean field would be a check-box.
- An object field would provide a panel of this same form conforming to that object's schema.

Ideally there would be some way to save specific objects for re-use too.

Does anything like this already exist? In my head it seems like something that would but maybe not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer for this question is already answered here.

**Link:** [GUI-based or Web-based JSON editor that works like property explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998832/gui-based-or-web-based-json-editor-that-works-like-property-explorer)

Answer (score 3):

I created a tool specifically for this purpose called [Mock Turtle](https://mockturtle.net/). It lets you import a JSON Schema and will produce a GUI tree that conforms to the schema.

You can customise the fields in the tree with various data types (e.g. name, address, email, etc.). It will then generate random JSON data based on your tree.

You can also save a tree that you have created/customised and import it again later for reuse.

[image]